# Activity calls onCreate on Back

Tags: java, android, android-activity, oncreate

I have an Activity called A and some event on Activity A calls Activity B. Now when I use the up-navigation in the Activity B, it comes back to Activity A but also calls the onCreate method. If I use the hardware/soft keys for the back, it does not call the onCreate and just comes back to Activity A where it was left. How do I make the up-navigation behave the same way?

My onCreate makes network calls asynchronously. Making another call just wastes data and time.
This is the code I use to launch activity B from activity A.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newsIndexActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("CityName", cityName.getText());
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Could you provide some of our source code?

Comment: don't fight with the system: your parent activity can be destroyed at any time so you need to be prepared that it is created from the scratch (onCreate being called)

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, can I check if my activity is destroyed? If not destroyed, why create it again?

Comment: if onCreate is called it means the old one was destroyed

Comment: But it is there if I use the back button, even after 5 minutes.

Comment: so see what is done when back button is pressed: http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#onBackPressed

Answer (score 5):

Up and back navigation are not the same, if you want your Up navigation button to behave like back button you should do something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true; 
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

If possible you should take a look to this link:

- http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

There you can have more information about this.

Comment: Tried that. Still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring parent activities’ launchMode as singleTop, we prevent the system from creating a new activity each time we press Up.

Comment: This worked for me. I added android:launchMode="singleTop" to the relevant activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code seems difficult to resolve, but the most probably cause is that you are calling to `startActivity`. Just close your current activity using  `finish()` and using the backstack it should behave as expected.

Answer (score -3):

Just call finish() or onBackPressed() method in your button callback listener.

```
finish();
super.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: `supre.onBackPressed();`. you misspelled `super`. `super.onBackPressed();` calls already `finish()`

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work. OnCreate is called everytime I use the UP Button.